# Can't write HTML entities with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

i'm trying to write the "times" html entity (×),
but BeautifulSoup automatically overrides my Ampersand to be it's html entity.

I tried to use html.unescape and also make my own formatter to ignore the default one,
but it didn't work.

```
parser = BeautifulSoup(open(template_path), 'html.parser')
span = parser.new_tag("span")
span.string = "&times;"
```

Which outputs:

```
<span>&amp;times;</span>
```

Instead of:

```
<span>&times;</span>
```

Comment: Why don't you enter the unicode value of this character directly like this for example:  `span.string = "×"`  ?

Comment: I tried it, when i open the browser it shows an "Invalid" sign instead of "x"